# Adobe Flash CS3 cut and paste movieclip within library

Tags: cut-and-paste

I have a scene named 1.fla. It contains a MovieClip named "MyClip". I want to cut and paste it into another scene named 2.fla. If I use standard operation Ctrl+X, Ctrl+V, it copies MyClip, but in "Symbol Properties" window, "Browse" still refers to that 1.fla. It seems that it copies some sore of link, not the object itself.
How do I completely remove MyClip from 1.fla and insert it into 2.fla?

Answer (score 0):

The most reasonable way I have found is making the symbol point to itself. This is also what Flash does if you duplicate a symbol.

- Save your file, then go to the symbol properties.
- Under "Source", click "Browse" and locate 2.fla - after selecting it, you'll notice that this clears the "File" field.
- Locate the symbol you are changing, and select OK.